# Why is SFINAE unable to detect constexpr on MSVC?

Tags: c++, constexpr, sfinae

I have written the following compile time check to detect if the size method is constexpr. Sadly this doesn't work as expected. It returns true for std::vector. I tought instantiating std.:integral_constant with the result of size would trigger SFINAE, because the argument has to be known at compile time. Why is the result still true?

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct ConstexprSize : std::false_type
{ };

template <typename T>
struct ConstexprSize<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::integral_constant<decltype(std::declval<T>().size()), std::declval<T>().size()>{})>>
    : std::true_type
{ };

constexpr bool test = ConstexprSize<std::vector<double>>::value; // true
```

Comment: Works as expected for clang/msvc [here](https://godbolt.org/z/of7nbPv4q). (gcc triggers an internal `static_assert`).

Comment: FWIW since c++20 [`std::vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is declared `constexpr`.

Comment: I explicitly use C++17